# Where does the OpenSSL C library Flush the socket

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

So the python OpenSSL implementation (TLSLite) is pretty straightforward, the flush command is the following:    `self.socket.sendall(buf)` So it is using the sendall function from the python socket library.

But the C implementation is confusing. I have to explain a few things before I get to the BIO_Flush function in C.

In the main I use the function `SSL_set_fd(*ssl, *sockfd);`, this does the following it creates a BIO `bio = BIO_new(fd_method(s));`, where the bio->method is fd_method. fd_method returns `BIO_s_socket()` which is

```
    static const BIO_METHOD methods_sockp = {
    BIO_TYPE_SOCKET,
    "socket",
    bwrite_conv,
    sock_write,
    bread_conv,
    sock_read,
    sock_puts,
    NULL,                       /* sock_gets,         */
    sock_ctrl,
    sock_new,
    sock_free,
    NULL,                       /* sock_callback_ctrl */
};
```

So the bio->method is the above struct that contains various functions, for us the **sock_ctrl** is of importance.

Now in the client state machine, during the post work state machine the flushing happens using the command `int statem_flush(SSL_CONNECTION *s)`. This function calls `BIO_flush(s->wbio)` which is basically

`# define BIO_flush(b)            (int)BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_CTRL_FLUSH,0,NULL)`

And now the interesting part BIO_ctrl does `ret = b->method->ctrl(b, cmd, larg, parg);`, and in my case that would be **sock_ctrl**. As we can see BIO_ctrl sends the **BIO_CTRL_FLUSH** so lets see what sock_ctrl does.

```
    case BIO_CTRL_FLUSH:
    ret = 1;
    break;
```

For the FLUSH case it basically does nothing, it just returns 1. So I don't understand why BIO_flush even works, but it does work since I tested it.

I was looking through other scenarios and in the case of a file pointer a differnet ctrl is used, file_ctrl uses the fflush function which makes sense, but SSL_set_fd doesn't assign this ctrl so yea...

```
    case BIO_CTRL_FLUSH:
    st = b->flags & BIO_FLAGS_UPLINK_INTERNAL
            ? UP_fflush(b->ptr) : fflush((FILE *)b->ptr);
```

Comment: Sockets don't need flushing unless there is an application-side buffer, which in this case there evidently isn't.

Comment: Openssl does use a buffer, but besides that if I comment out the statem_flush the message won't be sent.

Comment: Not possible if your analysis is correct. *Ergo* it isn’t.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know which function statem_flush really is. Since the one I found it out to be does nothing. But in reality it has to do something because if I comment it out the specific message will not be sent. (If I comment out statem_flush when the client needs to send Finished the message won't be sent and so on...)